# Getting error in flutter web TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'statusCode')

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am getting an error when running flutter web. Flutter web app is stuck at splash screen and throwing this error in logs

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'statusCode')
at ApiErrorHandler.getMessage (http://localhost:60117/packages/flutter_grocery/data/datasource/remote/exception/api_error_handler.dart.lib.js:96:42)
at splash_repo.SplashRepo.new.getConfig (http://localhost:60117/packages/flutter_grocery/data/repository/splash_repo.dart.lib.js:52:91)
at getConfig.throw ()
at http://localhost:60117/dart_sdk.js:43069:38
at _RootZone.runBinary (http://localhost:60117/dart_sdk.js:42924:58)
at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleError (http://localhost:60117/dart_sdk.js:37506:33)
at handleError (http://localhost:60117/dart_sdk.js:38104:51)
at _Future._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:60117/dart_sdk.js:38130:17)
at [_completeError] (http://localhost:60117/dart_sdk.js:37963:23)
at [_completeError] (http://localhost:60117/dart_sdk.js:37406:36)
at _SyncCompleter.new.completeError (http://localhost:60117/dart_sdk.js:37326:29)
at onError (http://localhost:60117/dart_sdk.js:37160:60)
at _RootZone.runBinary (http://localhost:60117/dart_sdk.js:42924:58)
at _FutureListener.then.handleError (http://localhost:60117/dart_sdk.js:37506:33)
at handleError (http://localhost:60117/dart_sdk.js:38104:51)
at _Future._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:60117/dart_sdk.js:38130:17)
at [_completeError] (http://localhost:60117/dart_sdk.js:37963:23)
at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:60117/dart_sdk.js:38015:31)
at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:60117/dart_sdk.js:43223:13)
at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:60117/dart_sdk.js:43229:13)
at http://localhost:60117/dart_sdk.js:38359:9

This code is working fine in android and iOS.but giving error in Web.

splash_provider.dart

```
class SplashProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final SplashRepo splashRepo;
  SplashProvider({@required this.splashRepo});

  ConfigModel _configModel;
  BaseUrls _baseUrls;
  int _pageIndex = 0;
  bool _fromSetting = false;
  bool _firstTimeConnectionCheck = true;

  ConfigModel get configModel => _configModel;
  BaseUrls get baseUrls => _baseUrls;
  int get pageIndex => _pageIndex;
  bool get fromSetting => _fromSetting;
  bool get firstTimeConnectionCheck => _firstTimeConnectionCheck;

  Future<bool> initConfig(BuildContext context) async {
    ApiResponse apiResponse = await splashRepo.getConfig();
    bool isSuccess;
    if (apiResponse.response != null && apiResponse.response.statusCode == 200) {
      _configModel = ConfigModel.fromJson(apiResponse.response.data);
      _baseUrls = ConfigModel.fromJson(apiResponse.response.data).baseUrls;
      isSuccess = true;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      isSuccess = false;
      print(apiResponse.error);
      showCustomSnackBar(apiResponse.error.toString(), context,isError: true);
      }
    return isSuccess;
  }


  void setFirstTimeConnectionCheck(bool isChecked) {
    _firstTimeConnectionCheck = isChecked;
  }

  void setPageIndex(int index) {
    _pageIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<bool> initSharedData() {
    return splashRepo.initSharedData();
  }

  Future<bool> removeSharedData() {
    return splashRepo.removeSharedData();
  }

  void setFromSetting(bool isSetting) {
    _fromSetting = isSetting;
  }
  String getLanguageCode(){
    return splashRepo.sharedPreferences.getString(AppConstants.LANGUAGE_CODE);
  }

  bool showIntro() {
    return splashRepo.showIntro()??true;
  }

  void disableIntro() {
    splashRepo.disableIntro();
  }


}
```

Please help me

Comment: can you provide the source code for `ApiErrorHandler.getMessage` please ?

Answer (score 0):

ApiErrorHandler.getMessage is giving null.  Perhaps because you need to include an await and provide UI in the meantime, but without that code, can't say for sure.  But the error is clearly saying that ApiErrorHandler.getMessage isn't giving you anything, but you're trying to read it.  You have to null check on ApiErrorHandler.getMessage before trying to read it.